# App icons for launcher - which drawable sizes are necessary

Tags: android, icons

I offer the ability to change the app icon via a setting... I'm thinking about adding app icons in all material colors (500 + 900 values) which results in 34 icons + 2 for black and white.

Now I'm thinking of adding them only in a few resolutions instead of all. Which one can I safely remove?

I would add:

- mdpi
- hdpi
- xhdpi
- xxhdpi
- xxxhdpi

Would it work if I only add xxxhpi icons? Or xxxhdpi + hdpi? Which sizes are necessary so that it always works?

**EDIT**

Why do I want to do this? Just to keep my app as small as possible but having nice icons for all devices

Answer (score 1):

its best to have images in all size of same name,it will take the image  based on the resolution of the device